# How to aggregate rows in Google Bigtable

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I need to save error logs in Google Bigtable. Every log belongs to a project which represents any kind of service. The following query needs to be supported.

Get all unique errors **between a given start and end date** with the **number of times they occurred**. The **order should be descending**, so that the latest errors come first. For example, there are three errors. Two of them are similar, they just occurred at a different time. The corresponding query should return two errors, whereas one of them has a count of 2 to indicate that his error occurred twice.

Each error has a fingerprint, which is a hash of the error message and stack trace.

#### Alternatives:

I'm now wondering how to design the row key to perform the query mentioned above.

**a) Using project ID and fingerprint.**

`reversed_projectID#fingerprint`

If a new error occurs, it will check if a similar error already exists and increments its count if appropriate. Otherwise, it creates a new row with a count of 1. On the other hand, I don't see how the descending order could be provided.

**b) Storing each error in a separate row.**

`reversed_projectID#reversed_timestamp`

This would solve the problem with the descending order but doesn't aggregate similar errors. If someone, for example, wants to see all unique errors for a given time range and the range contains, for instance, four unique errors but each error occurred 50.000 times, I would need to perform a row scan over 200.000 rows and aggregate them on the server.

Does anyone have an idea for a possible solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into this [documentation](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages) which discusses the log entry format in Cloud Error Reporting, with examples of [JSON representation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages#json_representation). This shall help you structuring the data for [writing to BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writing-data) using the MutateRow API request. If you wish to leverage BigQuery’s capabilities on the newly created database afterward, you may refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable).